# How to clean transpiled js files in angular2 using npm?

Tags: angular, npm

Is there a command to clean the generated files in angular2 using npm? I am looking for an equivalent of an mvn clean in maven.

Comment: [npm del](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del)?

Comment: Depends on how you have your solution setup. Normally one would have a gulp/grunt 'clean' task that would do this. That can be exposed from npm scripts so you could run it with something like: 'npm run clean'